# How to resolve bower issue: "ENORESTARGET Tag/branch master does not exist"

Tags: bower, bower-install

I cannot seem to get bower working on my current project.
The project began as a yeoman 'angular' app a couple weeks ago, and now cannot remember exactly what I did, nor can I determine how to fix it.

I do not have a `bower_components` directory, and have deleted and re-created `bower.js` several times.

**`bower.json`**

```
{
  "name": "my_name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "app/index.html",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true
}
```

**`$ bower install jquery`**

```
bower jquery#*                  cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.1
bower jquery#*                validate 2.1.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower jquery#*            ENORESTARGET Tag/branch master does not exist

Additional error details:
No tags found in git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
No branches found in git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
```

It *looks* like this error is telling me that the jquery project doesn't have a master branch? ([it does](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/branches))

I created a fresh project, and did a `bower init`, then ran the same command (`bower install jquery`). Doing this works as expected, and jquery is installed without error.

**`$ bower install jquery`**

```
bower jquery#*                  cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.1
bower jquery#*                validate 2.1.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower jquery#~2.1.1            install jquery#2.1.1

jquery#2.1.1 bower_components/jquery
```

I *still* cannot get my original project to work.

**What is it that is causing this problem, and how can I resolve it?**

---

### UPDATE

I was able to resolve this issue by deleting all the hidden `.git*` files.

- contents of `.git/`
- `.gitignore`
- `.gitattributes`

I guess it follows that somehow git was caching something incorrectly? I'd really like to know what it was causing it to not work properly. I'll leave this question open for a bit in case someone has any insight as to what the cause of all this is. Otherwise I'll answer myself a bit later on...

Comment: I also have this issue. My message is: bower ENORESTARGET  Tag/branch current does not exist And I don't use git on this project.

Comment: @StephaneEybert probably worth opening your own question for it then... link it here if you want and I'll take a look.

Comment: I have solved the issue, but my memory is blurry on this :-) I think I deleted the bower_components directory.

Answer (score 12):

if you use cmder or ConEmu (both are simple terminal commander) go to options and uncheck "Inject ConEmuHk" option, your problem will be resolve ...!

more info : [main response(in near of last answer)](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/852)

Comment: Perfect, this resolve several days of headaches! thanks @sajjad

Comment: @xzegga I'm lucky I only wasted a few hours (and pulled a few hairs)

Comment: Thanks. This saved me from wasting so much time! :)

Comment: It's in Settings > Features > In-console options. Took me a while to find it.

Comment: how to fix it, if we are using windows cmd?

Answer (score 4):

Be careful ! it can be your command line tool that causes this problem. 
For me the problem was resolved using [ConEmu](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) and the bug was caused by a version of **Cmder**

Comment: It took me forever to realize this might be the problem... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me from within a Jenkins build, and wiping out the workspace did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and removed the git files as suggested in a previous answer.

NG.

Then I removed bower.json. That fixed the problem.

Fortunately I work in a VM environment and fortunately I took a snapshot before I started deleting stuff (highly recommended practice). So I restored the snapshot and applied the right fix:

```
  rm bower.json
  bower init
```

`bower init` asks a bunch of questions. I pretty much took the defaults. It restored my `bower.json` dependencies based on what I had already installed in `bower_components`

Voila!

My unloadable package now loads.