# Trouble installing bootstrap on Mac OS with bower install -g (have installed git)

Tags: git, macos, bower

I have looked through various answers but cannot seem to determine a solution to my specific issue. I installed node.js on my macbook air (10.7.5). I installed bower. All successful. Then when I try to install bootstrap, I get the following error.

```
$ bower install -g bootstrap

bower not-cached    git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*

bower resolve       git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*

bower ENORESTARGET  Tag/branch master does not exist

Additional error details:

No tags found in git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git

No branches found in git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git


# The following command works:

$ which git

/usr/local/bin/git


# I tried this (some suggestion from another post):

$ git clone https://github.com/git/git

Illegal instruction: 4
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually you install bower inside the directory of your project. You start by installing bower (which you've already done). Then you initialise it in your project by using `bower init`. This will look something like:

```
$ bower init
? name test
? description bla bla some 
? main file 
? what types of modules does this package expose? 
? keywords 
? authors Haroen Viaene <hello@haroen.me>
? license MIT
? would you like to mark this package as private which prevents it from being accidentally published to the registry? (y/N) y
{
  name: 'test',y? (y/N) 
  authors: [
    'Haroen Viaene <hello@haroen.me>'
  ],
  description: 'bla bla some',
  main: '',
  moduleType: [],
  license: 'MIT',
  homepage: '',
  ignore: [
    '**/.*',
    'node_modules',
    'bower_components',
    'test',
    'tests'
  ]
}

? Looks good? Yes
```

Then you can install `bootstrap` by doing `bower install --save bootstrap`. This should look like:

```
$ bower install --save bootstrap
bower cached        git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.6
bower validate      3.3.6 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower cached        git://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.2
bower validate      2.2.2 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#1.9.1 - 2
bower install       bootstrap#3.3.6
bower install       jquery#2.2.2

bootstrap#3.3.6 bower_components/bootstrap
└── jquery#2.2.2

jquery#2.2.2 bower_components/jquery
```

Now `bootstrap` should be installed in your `bower_components` folder.

Comment: Thanks but I had installed bower in the directory of my project and done bower init. All that went well. Then I tried to install bootstrap with bower and I got enogit. So I installed git and retried and got the above error. Then looking at another post, I uninstalled bower (since it had been installed before git). Then I reinstalled bower and did bower init. Then again tried bootstrap install but still got same message.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24234063/3185307 (removing the contents of `.git/`, `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes`