# Ionic build/run not working with Cmdr

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic project and use [Cmdr](http://cmder.net/) as command line tool.

Everything is working fine during development, but when I wanted to build and run for android, it fails with this error:

```
Error: Please install Android target: "android-23".
Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: "C:\Users\s.fave\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat"
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
```

But everything is correctly installed, and thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35313921/3493954), I tryed with the native Windows cmd and it worked like a charm!

When I run (in Cmdr) `android` to launch the SDK manager, it says there is `No suitable Java found`, but `echo %PATH%` and `echo %JAVA_HOME%` prints the correct values with Java path.

I suspect a path issue with Cmdr, but I can't figure it out :(
Is there a specific configuration of Cmdr needed to be able to use `ionic build/run` commands?

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434517/ionic-on-windows-android-sdk-installed-still-get-error-please-install-androi

Comment: Already tried that! That's the same link I posted in my question....

Comment: for using ionic i think there is no need to provide the path of java we only need sdk path

Comment: check your sdk path and update the android sdk tool may be that can fix the problem

Comment: In my `%Path%` I correctly have the path to `sdk\tools` and `sdk\tools\ant`. And SDK is already up to date

Comment: **1. "SDK Platform" for android-23** this error occurs because of required android 23 platform is not updated in sdk manager

Comment: If you read my question, you will see that everything is updated because it's working well when using the Windows native command prompt. I just want to find a way to make it work when using Cmdr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a bower issue with Cmdr, I finally [found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838715/3493954) !

In Cmder `options > features`, I unchecked `Inject ConEmuHk` and now I can build from Cmdr :)